# how can i change @gorhom/bottom-sheet's BottomSheetModal bottom radius

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I want to give margins from the bottom and both sides.

so i gave margins backgroundcomponent it doesn't work i expected

I using BottomSheetFlatList in BottomSheetModal (@gorhom/bottom-sheet )

[this is my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9olJ.png)

[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn5vY.png)

```
      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={yearBottomSheetModalRef}
        index={0}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
        handleIndicatorStyle={{backgroundColor: '#E8EAED'}}
        bottomInset={170}
        backgroundComponent={renderBackground}
        style={{
          marginHorizontal: 16,
          marginBottom: 17,
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}>
        <BottomSheetFlatList data={YEAR_DATA} renderItem={yearRenderItem} />
      </BottomSheetModal>
```

```
  const renderBackground = useCallback(
    (props: any) => <BottomSheetBackground {...props} />,
    [],
  );
```

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const BottomSheetBackground = ({style}: any) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={[{backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: 20}, {...style}]}></View>
  );
};

export default BottomSheetBackground;
```

but it's not working

can i set bottomradius for bottomsheetbackground?

Answer (score 0):

I think to archive this kind of view, you can use [react-native-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal) instead of bottom sheet and customise it as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can add [detached](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props#detached) prop to `BottomSheetModal`, this will make BottomSheetModal to detach from the bottom of the screen.

adjust your BottomSheetBackground & BottomSheetModal child style with `marginBottom` and `borderRadius`

```
<BottomSheetFlatList 
  style={{
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
  }}
/>
```